# Will upgrading to Windows 10 affect my dual-boot setup?

Tags: release-freya, dual-boot, microsoft-windows

I'm not eligible, yet, to update to Windows 10, but I'm considering updating as soon as the update is available.

As you might understand as a developer I use both OS's, but elementary OS is my main OS.

So what I want to know is, if anyone using dual boot has updated to Windows 10? Are there any consequences?

Comment: my problem is similar to OP. I have two os in my drive. One is windows 7 and the other is windows 8.1. My main os is the windows 7 but the update of windows 10 comes on my windiws 8.1 . if I upgrade my windows 8.1 to windows 10 does it not affect my windows 7?

Comment: I did have problems. The upgrade wouldn't install at all until I wiped my Linux partition and removed Grub. It just gave some generic error like "Something Happened." I don't remember for sure, but it worked fine after. I had always had problems with Windows 8.1 installing updates, so I think there may have been something wrong underlying my system the entire time. My suspicion is that the Active Partition was marked incorrectly, but I didn't test that theory. I've reinstalled Linux and Grub, and am now dual booting again. Everything seems to be working properly now, so I guess whatever the is

Comment: I had the same issue as rft183. After the upgrade to windows 10, I was sent to the grub rescue menu. Using boot-repair, I was able to get windows 10 to boot up. I used testdisk to try and recover the partition, but it says that my harddrive is too small and the linux partition cannot be recovered. I've been manually backing up some important files, and I'm going to get a external HD to back up the partition to. Then I'll try to recover using testdisk. I did a fresh install of windows 10 on another laptop today and I noticed that it installed 4 partitions. 1 for backup, 2 for system files(?), a

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While your other operating system will be intact, updater will install new windows loader and you will have to restore your grub. Meaning that you should have linux live CD / usb at hand to restore grub.

Help on how to do this can be found in various places including help ubuntu.

[Help ubuntu: Recovering Ubuntu After Installing Windows](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows)
or use [Boot Repair Tool](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

If your machine uses UEFI, like most new hardware (no legacy boot enabled), grub might (should ?) survive just fine and everything will work just as expected, but I'm not able to verify this right now.

Answer (score 3):

I just upgraded by replacing my Windows 7 install with Windows 10 (I couldnt just upgrade; long story). I have 3 drives in my setup: 2 for elementary OS and 1 for windows, grub is installed on the root drive of elementary OS.

Before the installation I unplugged all non windows drives and I didnt even have to reconfigure grub after the installation.

Long story short: I had no issues.

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded my windows 8.1 to windows 10 and it did not affect my Elementary OS install. EFI boot remained intact. The only issue I had while upgrading windows was it would reboot to continue installing and boot into Elementary and I would have to reboot into windows to continue the upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Windows can not do some updates by starting over grub !

you must restore the windows bootloader !

run cmd as administrator 
type:

```
bootsect /nt60 c: /mbr
```

now you can reboot and windows 10 will perform his updates !

After updating windows you have to restore your grub !
you can take **debian install cd** (ubuntu have rescue mode only on lubuntu alternate cd ) and **start in rescue mode**
choose language ... at network configuration go back and enter rescue mode
then run a cmd on your linux partition ubuntu/debian/mint /dev/sda2 ... or other

type :

```
grub-install /dev/sda
```

then :

```
update-grub
```

now reboot

Answer (score 0):

I just want to point out, that updating from 8.1 to windows 10 without doing a clean install is painless.

Or at least in my case it was painless, except for the part where Windows restarts 6 times while updating.

So if you have elementary as your main option on grub consider changing it temporarily, or else you will need to be checking your pc from time time, just to see if it has restarted and entered elementary OS.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same (positive!) experience as other folks here. The Windows 8.1 -> 10 upgrade went perfectly for me.

I had grub set up to boot into Windows automatically after a few seconds, which allowed the whole thing to run unattended. For more info on how to do that, see [this answer on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52963/how-do-i-set-windows-to-boot-as-the-default-in-the-boot-loader/52990#52990).

Comment: please try to provide some content with the answer rather than links